# Is it recommended to start all the services in ambari in order to speed up the communication?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

Is it recommended to start all the services in "Ambari", in 
order to speed up the communication.

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking. Speed up the communication of what exactly?

Comment: Speed up the pace to complete the "Hadoop 101" course on cognitiveclass.ai, that is what he means.

Answer (score 3):

**No, You don't need to start all services to speed up communication.
because you already built-up communication with ambari when you setting up your initial cluster or adding nodes**.

Now ambari automatically built communication between component and services when you going to start with ambari web console.